# Regex Help. What am I doing wrong

Tags: c#, regex, string, string-comparison

Can somebody please help me and let me know what am I doing wrong? 
I am writing in code behind in C#.
I am trying to find if my multiline textbox value contains HREF or href or `<a href` or `</a>` or `<A HREF`.

This is what I tried with Regex. But it gives me the parsing error saying Too many...
Please help.
Thanks

```
Regex strMatch = new Regex(@"^(HREF|href|<a href|</a>))", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is anchored at the start of the string, so it would only match if your string started with one of the four options.

Additionally, you have an extra `)` that's resulting in an invalid regex syntax.

Try this instead:

```
Regex strMatch = new Regex(@"(?:<a )?href|</a>"
    ,RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This will match your four cases, since the first two are identical (thanks to `IgnoreCase`), and the first is a substring of the third.

Comment: No. String may or may not start with one of the four options. So how to check that? I am new to .Net.

Comment: You only said "contains" in your question, you never said anything about it having to be at the start. In that case, you want `@"^(?:(?:<a )?href|</a>)"`

Comment: One more quick question. Can I do something similar in Javascript?
If so how? I need to do the same check in the Preview button before opening a child window as well as Save button.

Comment: Of course. In fact, it's almost identical: `/^(?:(?:<a )?href|<\/a>)/`

Comment: Sorry..new to .net as well as JS. So do I use the same regex? Can you please write the full line code. Thanks a ton.

Comment: var strMatch = (/^(?:(?:<a )?href|<\/a>)/) ; Is this how we use?